# AbortController aborting ahead of time

Tags: javascript, network-programming, fetch-api

What I want to achieve is to abort previous request after user had changed filters.
I have tried this:

```js
const API_URL = "https://www.example.com"

const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;

export const fetchData = async (filters) => {
    // this console.log is fired only once
    console.log("Below I thought it would abort a request if ongoing, and ignore otherwise");
    controller.abort();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products?${filters}`, { method: "GET", signal });
    return await response.json();
}
```

But what happens is my request being aborted even on first invoke, kind of ahead of time.
Other thing I tried is managing `AbortController` like so:

```js
let controller;
let signal;

export const fetchData = async (filters) => {
    if (controller) {
        console.log("aborting")
        controller.abort();
        controller = null;
        fetchData(filters); // won't work until I invoke this function here recursively
        // and I expected something like 
        // controller = new AbortController();
        // signal = controller.signal;
        // ... then the rest of the function would work
    } else {
        controller = new AbortController();
        signal = controller.signal;
    }
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products?${filters}`, { method: "GET", signal });
    console.log("fetch fulfilled")
    return await response.json();
}
```

But the above approach wouldn't work if I don't include recursive call of `fetchData` because calling `controller.abort()` caused the whole function to throw error and not perform until the end, after the `if` block.
And this would leave me happy if it worked, but `"fetch fulfilled"` is logged out twice. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's already a controller, you're both calling `fetchData` (in the `if` branch) **and** doing the fetch later; that branch doesn't terminate the function. So you end up with two fetches and two "fulfilled" messages.

Simplifying the code should sort it out (see `***` comments):

```
let controller; // Starts out with `undefined`

export const fetchData = async (filters) => {
    // Abort any previous request
    controller?.abort(); // *** Note the optional chaining
    controller = new AbortController(); // *** Controller for this request
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products?${filters}`, {
        method: "GET",
        signal: controller.signal, // *** Using this controller's signal
    });
    console.log("fetch fulfilled");
    // *** Note: You need a check `response.ok` here
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
};
```

Comment: This is working as expected. Thank you